# I need an Input Box entry to do two things

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro with an input box to select a range of cells.
I also want the range coordinates selected to show somewhere so I can check it.

Here is the main part of the code I have:

```
Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Set DataRange = Application.InputBox("Please select INBOUND range", Default:="A:L", Type:=8)
    DataRange.Select
    Selection.Copy
```

The columns are preselected (A:L) and I insert the beginning row after A:, and ending row after L. So, if I enter 10 & 50, I get the range (A10:L50), but those coordinates are then gone. I want "A10:L50" to show in a cell somewhere.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `range("a1").value=datarange.address`

Comment: What do you mean they are gone? They are stored in a variable, right? You can simply access this variable and write it's `Address` property just as @SJR has showed you. Another note; `DataRange` has now been used as an range variable that will be using the implicit `ActiveSheet` as it's parent object. Never a really good idea.

Comment: Wondering if you are asking the right question here. What is your end goal here?

Comment: Thank You SJR - That was what I needed. I knew there was a simple code for it, I just couldn't think of the .address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will auto default to the active range. It is up to the user to select which range they would like and this can be consumed.

Just a word of caution, user selecting ranges can always be troublesome - user may not select all the data etc. Try controlling it in your code. you should see rangeselected variable in your locals window.

```
    Dim oSelect As Range
    Set oSelect = Application.InputBox("Range", , Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, , , , , 8)
    RangeSelected = oSelect.Address
```

Comment: Please don't skip optional parameters like this, use named arguments instead. `= Application.InputBox("Range", Default:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, Type:=8)`. Also beware of a type mismatch when the inputbox is cancelled and the function returns a `Boolean`.